# Icon list for Font Awsome 3.2

Tags: font-awesome

recently was released new version of Font Awesome 4.0. That's great! But is there any way how to get the list of icons for previous version 3.2?

I'm still using it and i cant remember all icon names. :) And also I can't upgrade to 4.0 or at least not now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excellent question.... !! I was wondering about the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icons/

I really think this should be linked somewhere on v4 site.

Also read [upgrade guide](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4) with full list of changed names.